how to connect react to springboot in K8s? frontend not visible on Loadbalancer IP!! React+SpringBoot+AKS,
Both pod's logs are clear, so not have anything to show! i can share the YAML file, in that i have mention
frontend.yml
env:
    - name: REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL
      value: "http://backend-service:8080"

from the backend.yml
ex.

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-service

